# Unique Indicial Equation of DE - Help Figuring Out?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm currently working on the following:
$$
x^2y'' + x(1+x+x^2)y' + x(2-x)y = 0
$$

I am a little thrown-off by there being an x-term in front of (2-x)y.  Initially my thought was that this had no impact, and that the indicial equation was $$r^2+2 = 0$$ but I now no longer believe this to be the case.

Can someone help me figure determining the indicial equation for a DE formatted this way?

Thanks!

EDIT: I think you can distribute the x to the (2-x) term to then give you an indicial equation of r^2 = 0

Answer (score 1):

The ODE is
$$x^2y'' + x(1+x+x^2)y' + x(2-x)y = 0$$

or

$$y'' + \frac{1+x+x^2}{x}y' + \frac{x(2-x)}{x^2}y = y'' + \frac{p(x)}{x}y' + \frac{q(x)}{x^2}y =0$$

According to wikipedia.org, the indicial equation is defined as:

$$0=r(r-1)+p(0)r+q(0)=r(r-1)+1\cdot r+0=r^2$$